# How to Constantly Update Microcontrollers via USB

Tags: dynamic

I have a computer that needs to constantly scan online information and then in accordance to what has been found, the micro controller ( assume an ardunio ) will act in a particular way.

However it seems that most micro controllers cannot be dynamically updated via USB cable. Is there a way to constantly give new instructions or commands to a previously uploaded program into the processor to make it do corresponding actions?

Thank you (I'm sorry if this isn't the right forum to post this question, but I couldn't find one for micro controllers :(   )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use serial communications. Install a special driver found on mbed, and then also use PySerial to be able to constanly update the mbed (Any other microcontroller would work)

Answer (score 0):

> However it seems that most micro controllers cannot be dynamically updated via USB cable

if you mean programming the microcontroller via usb then it is possible but not at all necessary. you could just send predefined instructions via USB (using [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php) for example) or UART (supported on most microcontrollers) or other data transfer protocols in order to change the state of your program on the hardware side.

if you're new to microcontrollers you should read one of many online tutorials on the subject. arduinos are specially designed for beginners and they have their own forums where you could ask questions. if you choose to go with AVR, i would recommend [avrfreaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum).

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont quite get it. If for example the computer returned a true statement what would be an appropriate method of sending that signal to the micro controller? Thank you (your explantion was good just that i needed to clarify my question )

Comment: @JohnHon sorry about the dealy. the easiest way would be through UART specially if the data isn't big. all microcontrollers support it and it provides up to ~115kbps. to connect it to the PC you'd need a "converter". there are tons of USB-UART modules that are usually basted on either the FT232 or PL2303 chips. i prefer FT232 because there are less fakes of it. another way would be using a Wifi module if you want to go wireless and they are available both with UART and SPI (another embedded transfer protocol with higher speed than UART) and for USB lufa ist the way to go,

Comment: I'm sorry, but i found a far more useful answer found on mbed.com -- serial communications